1C, macOS | Сломался масштаб окна
С недавних пор приложение стало открываться таким, будто интерфейс предназначен под более большое окно, возможно глюкнуло в момент работы с двумя мониторами или смены разрешение дисплея, пробывал переустанавливать, ничего не поменялось. Что с этим делать, как можно исправить? Может есть какой-то конфигурационный файл, в котором можно подправить размеры.


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Возможно поможет очистка кеша, тогда все настройки, в том числе и окон сбросятся на стандартные. Но вот где это храниться в MacOS не подскажу.
